# Difference in grouping sets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE #Product (ProductId INT, ProductName Varchar(500), Price MONEY)
INSERT INTO #Product (ProductId ,ProductName,Price)
VALUES(1, 'Test1', 12000),
   (2, 'Test2', 18000),
   (3, 'Test3', 25000),
   (4, 'Test4', 15000),
   (1, 'Test4', 15000)

SELECT ProductId ,ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product Group By
GROUPING SETS((ProductId), (ProductName), ())

SELECT ProductId ,ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product Group By
GROUPING SETS((ProductId, ProductName), ())
```

What difference does this two makes? and where to use the first and the second

Answer (score 1):

Check below link it's very Descriptive explanation of Grouping Sets.

[Grouping Sets Explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two queries is the number of groupings created.  The `GROUPING SETS` syntax can be thought of as a UNION ALL of each grouping set specified.

For example, let's look at the first query you wrote:

```
SELECT ProductId ,ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product Group By
GROUPING SETS((ProductId), (ProductName), ())
```

Here, you have specified three groupings:

1. ProductID
2. ProductName
3. Grand Total

This query is the equivalent of writing the following code:

```
SELECT ProductID, NULL AS ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product
GROUP BY ProductID
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, ProductName, SUM(Price)
FROM #Product
GROUP BY ProductName
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM(Price)
FROM #Product
```

Similarly, looking at your second query:

```
SELECT ProductId ,ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product Group By
GROUPING SETS((ProductId, ProductName), ())
```

This query performs two groupings:

1. ProductID and ProductName
2. Grand Total

This is equivalent to writing two groupings:

```
SELECT ProductId ,ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product
GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM #Product
```

As far as why you would use one and not the other: which groupings do you want?  Do you want the total by product ID, the total by product name, and the grand total?  Then use the first.  This may be useful if products can have the same name with different product IDs as in your example.

Do you want totals by product ID and product name and also the grand total?  Then use the second.